# Что происходит под капотом при создании файлового потока?

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных, filestream, clr

Сейчас читаю вот эту статью [Difference between Buffer & Stream in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43935608/2948684) и хотел бы для себя сначала уяснить что правильно понимаю, что происходит под капотом при выполнении инструкции `FileStream stream = new FileStream("filepath.txt", FileMode.open)`.

### Мое понимание происходящего

На HDD/SSD лежит некий файл `filepath.txt`, который может быть размером даже больше RAM. И при выполнении вышеприведенной инструкции, исполняющая среда как-бы подносит к началу этого файла шланг и открывает краник. Водичка (байты) сразу не течет, а просто на готове.

**Правильно ли я все описал?**

Comment: вы создали поток данных, но это просто, грубо говоря, инструкции откуда читать данные. Сами данные ещё не прочитаны.

Comment: если знаете C, то это тоже самое что и `fopen` + `fread/fwrite` по сути своей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Грубо говоря, поток - это место, откуда можно читать или куда модно писать данные. Это, если можно так выразиться, абстрактное понятие. 
Вот, например, мы создаем поток для доступа к файлу

```
using(var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
  ....
}
```

В примере создается экземпляр класса `FileStream`, который наследован от `Stream`. Это позволяет нам читать и писать в файл. 
Тип `MemoryStream` - представляет собой поток чтения/записи в память. `NetworkStream` - сеть. И так далее.

Итак, до этого момента мы говорили о потоке, который является источником и/или приемником данных. Но, помимо таких потоков, есть потоки - декораторы. Декораторы сами по себе не являются источниками или приемноками данных. Они принимают поток как параметр и используют его для операций чтения и записи. Для чего они нужны? Читаем далее.

Далее, `BufferedStream` - это декоратор над Stream. Он позволяет буферизировать запись/чтение в поток. Это полезно при файловом вводе/выводе, так как чтение/запись с использованием буфера уменьшает количество записей/считываний, что увеличивает производительность. Его можно использовать с любым потоком, например

```
using(var bufferedFileStream = 
  new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(path), 1024*1024)) // буфер в мегабайт
{
  ....
}
```

Как я сказал, `BufferedStream` - это декоратор, то есть он только расширяет возможности декорируемого потока. Вот [пример другого декоратора](https://github.com/tym32167/md5Reverse/blob/master/src/Md5Reverse.Lib/Utils/StreamSpy.cs) - я его использовал для мониторинга операций чтения/записи

```
public class StreamSpy : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _inner;
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public StreamSpy(Stream inner, ILog log)
    {
        _inner = inner;
        _log = log;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _inner.Flush();
        _log.Debug("Flush!");
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _inner.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _inner.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _log.Debug($"READ buffer {buffer.Length}, offset {offset}, count {count}, POSITION: {Position}");
        return _inner.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _inner.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        _log.Debug($"WRITE buffer {buffer.Length}, offset {offset}, count {count}");
    }

    public override bool CanRead => _inner.CanRead;
    public override bool CanSeek => _inner.CanSeek;
    public override bool CanWrite => _inner.CanWrite;
    public override long Length => _inner.Length;
    public override long Position
    {
        get => _inner.Position;
        set => _inner.Position = value;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        base.Close();
        _inner.Close();

        _log.Info("CLOSE");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _inner.Dispose();
        _log.Info("DISPOSE");
    }
}
```

Так как это просто декораторы, то их можно объединять, например

```
using(var bufferedFileStream = 
  new BufferedStream(new StreamSpy(File.OpenRead(path), mylog), 1024*1024)) // буфер в мегабайт
{
  ....
}
```

теперь конечный поток `bufferedFileStream` представляет собой буферизированный поток чтения/записи в файл с логгированием операций.

Соответсвенно, если вы читаете байт используя просто FileStream - вы прочитаете ровно байт. Если вы читаете байт из файловго потока, который декорирован буфером, то вы либо читаете с диска весь буфер, либо читаете данные из буфера в памяти.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что буферизирование это как-бы кэширование данных в оперативной памяти и позволяет не дергать каждый раз файловую систему, что естественно намного медленне?

Comment: @adamshakhabov да, что то типа кеша при чтении и буфера при записи

Answer (score 1):

> На HDD/SSD лежит некий файл filepath.txt, который может быть размером даже больше RAM. И при выполнении вышеприведенной инструкции, исполняющая среда как-бы подносит к началу этого файла шланг и открывает краник. Водичка (байты) сразу не течет, а просто на готове.

Да, ты приблизительно правильно написал. Только я бы обьяснил другими словами. **Поток - это канал для принятия/отсылания неких бинарных данных.** Канал работает непрерывно, а вот сами данные могут прерыватся. (по твоей алегории -- есть труба, но можно пускать воду[данные], а можно и не пускать)

Допустим, мы читаем через поток текстовый файл. Это значит, что сам поток ничего не знает про такую сущность как "строка", а значит и не может просто взять и прочитать одну строку. Зато поток знает про такую сущность как "байт".

Мы можем читать от начала файла *[или от последнего `/r/n`]* до следующего `/r/n` байт.  И это и будет считывание одной строки.

---

Вообще потоком может быть и канал для принимания/отловки событий с деталями этих событий. Допустим, в базе данных Realm ты можешь подписыватся на изменения результатов некоего Query(запроса). То есть если у тебя есть квери (условно) "достать всех пользователей с именем Вася" то при изменении хотя бы одного из Вась создастся событие, которое заново вышлет тебе результат этого квери по потоку вида:

- весь старый список данных(без изменений)
- какие конкретно и где именно изменения были сделаны в этих данных.