# Чтение больших файлов без нагрузки на память c#

Tags: c#

Есть большой текстовой файл (несколько гигов), нужно рассмотреть каждую строку не тратя много памяти.

Пытался так :

```
Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(path), opt, a => { Fil(a); opt.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); });
```

но память постепенно загружается. В методе Fil() я использую регулярное выражение.

Пытался и так

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(accpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Fil(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Эффект тот же, есть ли возможность не нагружать память вообще ?

Comment: а что у вас в методе Fil? Плюс ко всему память будет выделяться на прочитанные строки, а освобождаться только по необходимости.

Comment: @rdorn добавил метод Fil

Comment: во втором способе, где цикл, почему там не освобождается память прошлой строки, ведь берет же уже новую. Есть ли какой-то способ все же не тратить столько памяти ? то, что не сразу забивается память - это хорошо, но вот не забивать бы ее вообще

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Начну с конца...
**Второй вариант** - самый плохой, так как он использует BufferedStream. Тем самым, вы создаете еще один дополнительный буфер в памяти. По факту, у вас весь считанный файл будет находиться в оперативной памяти.

**Первый вариант** - зачем вы используете параллельное чтение? Замените ваш параллельный вариант на последовательный, чтобы более точно контролировать количество загруженных строк в память

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
     Fil(line);
}
```

При чтении файла с помощью функции ReadLines, в памяти выделяется буфер небольшого размера и файл будет считываться блоками. Из блока читается строка и возвращается из ReadLines. Если чтение блока движется к завершению, будет загружен следующий блок. Таким образом, у вас не будет большая нагрузка оперативной памяти.

Стоит отметить еще такой момент, что `.Net Runtime` память освобождает по необходимости. Память в приложении может не освобождаться, если GC посчитает, что так будет более оптимально для работы приложения. Зачем ему отдавать память, если он уже ее взял и ее никто не просит у него, если она может ему потребоваться в скором времени?

[GС(сборщик мусора) срабатывает, когда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection)

1. В системе мало оперативной памяти
2. Количество выделенной памяти для управляемых объектов превысил порог.Этот порог непрерывно корректируется по мере запуска процесса.
3. Вызывается явно метод GC.Collect[2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) для ручного запуск сборки "мусора". Почти во всех случаях вам не нужно вызывать этот метод, потому что сборщик мусора работает непрерывно. Этот метод в основном используется для уникальных ситуаций и тестирования.

Comment: я пробовал этот метод, он так же постепенно сильно нагружает память, нет ли метода, который бы освобождал память ?

Comment: Если не вызывать метод Fil, тогда все ок, но я не вижу, где бы я в методе Fil нагружал память

Comment: вы получаете исключение OutOfMemory?

Comment: `Стоит отметить еще такой момент, что .Net Runtime память освобождает по необходимости. ` , а, т.е в конечном итоге не будет ошибки systemoutmemory

Comment: я ее получал, когда грузил через ReadAllLines, когда начал тестить другие методы, то тоже заметил, что память постепенно сильно грузится  (достигало полу гига), и не доходил до конца и искал другой способ

Comment: Не будет, если память потребуется кому-то другому, или она будет заканчиваться - он ее освободит.

Comment: еще момент, я вызываю ваш код в новом потоке (дабы главный поток не грузить), но все равно главная форма виснет, как это можно исправить ?

Comment: создаю новый поток через Thread

Comment: если главный поток виснет, то значит что-то делаете не верно. А зачем вы создаете поток через Thread? Просто создайте новый [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и запустите в нем выполнение вашего кода.

Comment: АГА, я нашел причину почему у меня вдруг память нагружалась и форма висла. Все дело в выводе инфы на главную форму, через lock

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с этого.

```
Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(path), opt, a => { Fil(a); opt.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); });
```

Параллельное чтение из файла? Как вы себе это представляете?

Давайте кое что поясним:

```
1) Чтение с диска - медленная операция
2) Чем меньше чтений диска, тем лучше
3) Оперативная память не бесконечная
```

То есть, оптимальное чтение с диска в вашем случае - чтение с буфером.

[Как читать с буфером?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848342/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0/848376#848376)

```
using(var bufferedFileStream = 
  new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(path), 1024*1024)) // буфер в мегабайт
{
  ....
}
```

Внутри этой конструкции можете считывать так, как вам понравится. Хотите `StreamReader`? Оберните это всё в него и все дела

```
using(var reader = 
    new StreamReader(
        new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(path), 1024*1024) // буфер в мегабайт
        ))
{
  ....
}
```

так как чтение у вас будет однопоточное, то вам не надо морочиться с синхронизацией. Никаких конструкций lock дальше вам ставить не надо.

Comment: изначально я в ForEach кидал готовый массив, для этого он и задумывался, что бы быстрее расправится с массивом, потом понял, что файл большой, оперативки не хватит и уже выкручивался по ситуации. Самое интересное, что как раз конструкция lock .... вызывала нагрузку на память, убрал  ее - память не грузит. За ответ спасибо

Comment: @Lolidze `я ее получал, когда грузил через ReadAllLines` - есть разница между `ReadAllLines` и `ReadLines`. Первое грузит все сразу в память, в второе читает по строчке лениво. Возможно в этом было дело.