# Узнать количество строк в текстовом файле

Tags: c#, .net

Как возможно узнать количество строк у текстового файла? Сейчас я узнаю так:

```
int count = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path_base).Length;
```

Но этот способ занимает много времени и забивает оперативную память, при загрузке текстовых файлов размером более 1 гигабайта, это не актуально.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь ReadLines или если хотите тратить прямо минимум ресурсов, то [чтение с буфером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848342/Что-происходит-под-капотом-при-создании-файлового-потока/848376#848376), [чтение больших файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858569/Чтение-больших-файлов-без-нагрузки-на-память-c/858604#858604) - с этим можно просто посчитать количество переносов строки в файле

Comment: int count = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path_base).Count(); используя System.Linq, но тут нужно учитывать, что для 32 битных систем максимум файл в 4Gb, лучше использовать вариант из ответа ниже

Answer (score 2):

Пример с буфером в 10 мегабайт.

```
var linesCount = 1;
int nextLine = '\n';
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
    new BufferedStream(
        File.OpenRead(@"D:\temp\11.xml"), 10 * 1024 * 1024))) // буфер в 10 мегабайт
{
    while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        if (streamReader.Read() == nextLine) linesCount++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(linesCount);
```

Comment: вместо '\n' лучше использовать Enviroment.NewLine

Comment: @B.Vandyshev `Enviroment.NewLine` - это строка, а не символ. Я не могу сравнивать при чтении строку и символ. К тому же в винде это `\r\n`, в линуксе `\n`, то есть `\n` присутствует в любом случае, не зависимо от того, с каким окончанием строк сохранен файл.

Comment: @tym32167, а в маке вроде `\r`?

Comment: @Grundy про мак к сожалению не знаю

Comment: @Grundy [`Строка, содержащая "\r\n" для платформ, отличных от Unix, или строка, содержащая "\n" для платформ Unix.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @tym32167, ага, похоже уже [отказались от этого начиная с macos x](https://superuser.com/a/439443/761205)

Comment: @Grundy ну и здорово, значит ответ править не придется :)

Answer (score 1):

```
                int count = 0;
                string line;
                TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path_base);
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                reader.Close();
```

Comment: `File.ReadLines(path).Count()` - является эквивалентом вашего кода. Метод `ReadLines` не читает весь файл сразу, в отличие от `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: А если файл большой (гигабайты) и состоит из одной-единственной строки? Облом... Если нужно решение, работающее на любых входных данных, то нужно читать файл блоками и искать в них символы конца строки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можете подсказать как это реализовать? Чтобы найти в конце символ конца строки?

Comment: зачем вам сохранять стоку в line? Не оборачивать IDisposable в using не очень хорошо