# запись DataTable в CSV через StringBuilder C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть

```
DataTable Adress_for_mapping
```

Необходимо записать её в CSV файл построчно, потому что если записывать целый документ, то не хватает памяти для этого - OutOfMemoryException. Пробую это сделать вот так, всё работает, но очень долго:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

string[] columnNames = Adress_for_mapping.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
  Select(column => column.ColumnName).
  ToArray();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", columnNames));
File.AppendAllText(@".\Res_mapping.csv", sb.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
sb.Clear();

foreach (DataRow row in Adress_for_mapping.Rows)
{
  string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
    ToArray();
  sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", fields));   
  File.AppendAllText(@".\Res_mapping.csv", sb.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
  sb.Clear();
}
```

Comment: зачем писать одну строку в `StringBuilder` и сливать его в файл? Почему бы не писать строку сразу в файл?

Comment: "записывает данные в файл некорректно" - в чем заключается "некорректность", мы должны угадать?

Comment: Зачем на каждый чих открывать файл на запись? Почему бы не открыть файл на запись в начале вашего алгоритма, записать в него что хотите, и закрыть в конце алгоритма?

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://github.com/ClnViewer/Dictionary-CSV-Extensions правда это для работы с `Dictionary`, но методы записи по сути теже, с DataTable даже попроще будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему бы полностью не избавиться от `StringBuilder`? Пишем сразу в файл.
Благодаря некоторым допущениям получаем максимально компактный код.

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@".\Res_mapping.csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
{
    var columns = Adress_for_mapping.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
    streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(";", columns));

    foreach (DataRow row in Adress_for_mapping.Rows)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(";", row.ItemArray));
    }
}
```

Метод [DataColumn.ToString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumn.cs,2542723b855dea01,references) выдает имя колонки, так что можно убрать `Select`. Однако, если среди колонок есть вычисляемые, с непустым свойством `Expression`, тогда `Select` нужен. Вызов `ToArray` тоже не обязателен, т. к. одна из перегрузок `string.Join` принимает `IEnumerable`.

Метод `string.Join` также принимает на вход массив объектов, между тем `DataRow.ItemArray` им и является, так что лишние преобразования не нужны.

---

Код легко преобразовать в асинхронный, использовав методы `WriteLineAsync` (не забываем `async/await` где нужно).

Можно ещё сократить потребление памяти (вернее, облегчить работу сборщика мусора), избавившись от создания строк с помощью `string.Join`. Для этого используем метод `Write` - пишем каждый элемент сразу в файл. Естественно, код увеличится в размере.

---

Теперь немного критики.

Не используйте однобайтовую кодировку. Ведь если в ваших данных окажутся символы, не входящие в набор символов этой кодировки, то они в результате исчезнут. Используйте юникод: UTF-8 или UTF-16.

Что за название такое: `Adress_for_mapping`? Ознакомьтесь: [Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), [ещё сслыка](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md).

---

Этот код, так же, как и ваш, приведёт к неправильному результату, если в данных содержится символ-разделитель (в данном случае `;`). Нужно обрамлять такие поля в кавычки. Или взять стороннюю библиотеку, как предлагает Andrew, чтобы не мучаться вручную.

По поводу долгой работы кода. Если данных много - ничего с этим не поделать. Мы ограничены скоростью процессора и (в большей мере) скоростью накопителя.
На заметку: `DataTable` тоже весьма не быстр. Если есть возможность - переходите на коллекции строго типизированных объектов.

Answer (score 0):

## (ответ НЕ через StringBuilder )

> Зато учитывает полностью все подводные камни использования CSV формата. Например, экранирование строк-ячеек которые имеют знак-разделитель внутри или переход на следующую строку.... Что долго и муторно учитывать при собственной ручной реализации чтения CSV.

можно взять библиотеку с ответа: [Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-xlsx-csv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

и тогда выйдет что-то вроде:

```
Csv csv = new Csv(';'); //раз уж в твоем примере использовался этот разделитель

string[] columnNames = Adress_for_mapping.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
    Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();
csv.AddRow(columnNames);

foreach (DataRow row in Adress_for_mapping.Rows)
{
  string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
  csv.AddRow(fields);
}

csv.FileSave("c:\\file2.csv");
```

Comment: `если записывать целый документ, то не хватает памяти для этого`?

Comment: аа, пропустил этот момент.... Да, тогда это не катит как ответ =( Но на всякий случай оставлю как ответ гуглящим.

Answer (score 0):

Накатал на основе кода из вопроса

```
private void SaveDgvToFile(DataGridView dgv, char separator, string filePath)
{
    ClearFile(filePath);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine( GetDgvHeadersLine(dgv, separator) );

    for (int i = 0; i<= dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(  GetDgvDataStr(dgv, separator, i) );

        if (i%1000 == 0)// сохраняем каждые 1000 строк
        {
            AppendToFile(sb, string filePath);
            sb.Clear();
        }
    }
    AppendToFile(sb, string filePath);//сохраняем остаток

}

private string GetDgvHeadersLine(DataGridView dgv, char separator)
{
    string[] columnNames = dgv.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                               Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();

    return string.Join(separator, columnNames);
}

private string GetDgvDataStr(DataGridView dgv, char separator, int index)
{
    string[] fields = dgv.Rows[index].ItemArray.
                               Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();

    return string.Join(separator, columnNames);
}

private void AppendToFile(StringBuilder sb, string filePath)
{
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
}

private void ClearFile(string filePath)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath,string.Empty);
}
```

Код писал из головы в блокнот не проверяя. Так что могут быть синтаксические и мелкие логические ошибки.

Comment: зачем вам вообще `StringBuilder`? Ну и для каждой строчки открывать файл на запись?

Comment: @tym32167 для каждых 1000 строк, попрошу! Почему для каждой строчки? Ну можно сделать для каждых 10 000 строк....) Но я не знаю что там за данные и не будет ли OutOfMemory  в таком случае. А `StringBuilder` нужен что бы не плодить переобьявлений строк в памяти. А для чего он еще используется? :) Или есть какие-то замечания по поводу его использования?

Comment: ну и да, согласен что можно оптимизировать запись -- что бы открытие под запись осуществлялось только 1 раз. Но мне влом было (для этого нужно было гуглить ибо давно не работал с этим, а гуглить было влом)

Comment: конечно есть, 1) Вы используете StringBuilder как буфер записи на диск, которым он, по сути, не является 2) Магическое число 1000 ничего не говорит о размере записываемых данных 3) запись по 1000 строк с открыванием/закрыванием файла тоже может быть ооочень медленной, особенно если строк оч много. Как поступить? Писать обычным StreamWriter'ом с буфером, как [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848376/179763)